# Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The `SerializeXmlNode` function from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` class always outputs the value of the last child nodes of a XML as a string type in the serialization process, when sometimes you might need them to be serialized as an Integer or a Boolean.

Sample code:

```xml
<Object>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Title>mytitle</Title>
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</Object>
```

Output:

```js
{ "ID" : "12",
  "Title" : "mytitle",
  "Visible" : "false"
}
```

Desired output:

```js
{ "ID" : 12,
  "Title" : "mytitle",
  "Visible" : false
}
```

Is there a way to force a XML node to be serialized as a Integer or a Boolean?

Thank you.

Note: Please avoid posting workarounds when the XML is already serialized to a JSON string, as those workarounds are the ones that we are willing to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current JSON.NET build doesn't provide the requested feature, so I modified the source code to provide this functionality:

https://github.com/lukegothic/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs

This modification provides the XmlNodeConverter a way to read an optional attribute from XML nodes called "Type" that holds the desired serialization of a node value. By default, the converter serializes all values as string in the result JSON string, but now you can add an attribute that specifies the desired DataType output. The allowed types are Integer, Float, Boolean and Date.

For example, if you have this source XML:

```
<Object>
  <ID json:Type='Integer'>12</ID>
  <Title>mytitle</Title>
  <Visible json:Type='Boolean'>false</Visible>
  <Price json:Type='Float'>1.55</Price>
  <ExpirationDate json:Type='Date'>2013-12-31</ExpirationDate>
</Object>
```

It will be serialized as:

```
{
    "ID":12,
    "Title":"mytitle",
    "Visible":false,
    "Price":1.55,
    "ExpirationDate":"2013-12-31T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: your solution is good wanted to know if JSON.NET has considered to adopt to your solution?

Comment: It's a shame but I haven't got any feedback from them to implement this feature.

Comment: Tracking issue: [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean #1651](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1651), open as of Oct 2019.

Answer (score 12):

JSON.NET is not a tool for XML serialization. It's serialization of XML nodes is meant to provide one-to-one correspondence between XML and JSON. As attributes in XML can be only of type string, type information is not preserved during the serialization. It will be useless when deserializing back to JSON.

If you need to convert XML to JSON, I suggest using a DTO class which supports both XML and JSON serialization.

```
[XmlRoot ("Object"), JsonObject]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement, JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement, JsonProperty]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement, JsonProperty]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize from XML and then serialize to JSON:

```
public class Program
{
    private const string xml = @"
        <Object>
          <Id>12</Id>
          <Title>mytitle</Title>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Object>";

    private static void Main ()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Id": 12,
  "Title": "mytitle",
  "Visible": false
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, but that was not the point of the question. My question is asking if JSON.NET does provide a way to specify that an XML node should be serialized as a JS data type different than string. In the API documentation there is a way to force a node to be rendered as a JS array by adding an attribute to the XML node that you want to be serialized that way, I was wondering if there was a similar way to force the node serialization to a data type you want.

Comment: No, there is no way. Explanation "why" is in the first paragraph. Code here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs As you can see, values are always strings. No other converters understand deep structure of XML nodes.

Comment: Reviewing the source code you provided, it doesn't look too hard to alter the code to fit our needs. I'm going to modify the class and post the changes here if someone wants to add the requested functionality to their fork.