# Is there a way of Convert javascript object to XML and back - without making items strings

Tags: .net, xml, json

Is there a way to convert JSON to XML and back, without making all properties strings?

I've tried via NewtonSoft but properties seem to encapsulated as strings in quotes.

```
Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{id=2}", "data", True)
Dim sJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc.DocumentElement, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, True)
```

This unfortunately mean a json object like `{id=2}`, becomes `{id="2"}`.

Note: I want to save Javascript objects into SQL XML field, but then retrieve them in exactly the same format. (Using JSON.Stringify works correctly, but newtonsoft seems to add the quotes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611139/force-jsonconvert-serializexmlnode-to-serialize-node-value-as-an-integer-or-a-bo)

Comment: Its very close - they are going from XML -> JSON and also get the same type issues. However I'm hoping there might be a way of encoding the type from JSON into XML which can then be used on the convertion from xml->json to keep the type. also another library might be better at this than Newtonsoft.