# convert a Json value to Integer with Newtonsoft

Tags: xml, json, json.net

I am using the following code to add an attribute to my xml to designate that this node should return an Integer value when using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode.

I have incorporated the update from Newtonsoft into my referenced dll.

I am using the following code to add the attribute:

```
ele.SetAttribute("Integer", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json", "true");
```

where `ele` comes from `XmlElement ele = node as XmlElement;`

The result always ends up with something like this:

```
 "id": {
        "@Type": "Integer",
        "#text": "759263947"
      },
```

but what I need is

```
"id": 759263947
```

Please note that I use the exact same syntax to identify an an Array:

```
ele.SetAttribute("Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json", "true");
```

which is working just fine.

Laura

Comment: I can't find any [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) that says Json.NET supports `"{http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json}Integer" = "true"`.   As far as I know only `Array` is supported.  Have you seen otherwise?   Also, what does your XML look like?

Comment: There was a suggested change to source posted here with a link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611139/force-jsonconvert-serializexmlnode-to-serialize-node-value-as-an-integer-or-a-bo

Comment: <fulfillment>
 <tracking_number>937467375966</tracking_number>
 <tracking_url>http://www.google.com/search?q=937467375966</tracking_url>
<line_items json:Array="true">
 <id json:Integer="true">759263947</id>
 <quantity json:Integer="true">1.00000</quantity>
 </line_items>
 </fulfillment>

Comment: Are you using the source change here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611139/force-jsonconvert-serializexmlnode-to-serialize-node-value-as-an-integer-or-a-bo

Comment: yes, I am using the source change (replaced the XmlNodeConverter.cs with the posted code). Using this call where NewDoc = the Xml I posted above:  strJSON =                                JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(NewDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the variant version of `XmlNodeConverter` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611139/force-jsonconvert-serializexmlnode-to-serialize-node-value-as-an-integer-or-a-bo) and available here: https://github.com/lukegothic/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs,  it looks like you would need to do:

```
ele.SetAttribute("Type", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json", "Integer");
```

Or, for a double value:

```
ele.SetAttribute("Type", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json", "Float");
```

Alternatively, you could use Linq-to-JSON out-of-the-box to manually modify convert string values to numeric values, for instance:

```
        string xml = @"<fulfillment xmlns:json=""http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json""><tracking_number>937467375966</tracking_number><tracking_url>google.com/search?q=937467375966</tracking_url>; <line_items json:Array=""true""><id>759263947</id><quantity>1.00000</quantity></line_items></fulfillment>";
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        var obj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc));
        foreach (var value in obj.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.String))
        {
            long lVal;
            if (long.TryParse((string)value, out lVal))
            {
                value.Value = lVal;
                continue;
            }
            double dVal;
            if (double.TryParse((string)value, out dVal))
            {
                value.Value = dVal;
                continue;
            }
            decimal dcVal;
            if (decimal.TryParse((string)value, out dcVal))
            {
                value.Value = dcVal;
                continue;
            }
        }
        var json = obj.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: Once I handled the syntax properly as you have shown (can't believe I missed that....), I had to convert my value of 1.0000 to an Integer before it serialized, as the "Integer" type crashed in the Newtonsoft code with that value.  Thank you @dbc!  I'm rockin now.

Comment: I'm rocking too - could not change version of Newtonconverter due to other code depended on particular. The Linq-to-JSON thing, with addition of boolean values saved my day (whole week in fact)

Comment: The Linq-to-JSON answer failed to compile on my machine on 'OfType<JValue>()' but it lead me to step through all the descendants and change the values on each property that I wanted to change.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison - that's the extension method [`System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<TResult>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913.aspx) in System.Core.dll.  You might need to add a `using System.Linq;` statement.

Comment: Thanks @dbc. Adding "using System.Linq;" sorted my compile issue.