# C# force integer when converting XML to JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am attempting to convert XML into JSON in order to generate a HTTP POST request to an API. I am getting an error because one of the fields is meant to be an integer instead of a string. From what i have read adding "json:Integer="true"" to the node will cause it to become an int, but this doesnt seem to be working for me. Here is the xml and the resulting json. The arrays are working, but the integer is not.

```
<shipments json:Array="true" xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
    <shipment_tracking_number />
    <response_shipment_date>2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00</response_shipment_date>
    <response_shipment_method>UPS Ground</response_shipment_method>
    <expected_delivery_date>2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00</expected_delivery_date>
    <ship_from_zip_code>12345</ship_from_zip_code>
    <carrier_pick_up_date>2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00</carrier_pick_up_date>
    <carrier>UPS</carrier>
    <shipment_items json:Array="true">
        <shipment_item_id>FF12345K</shipment_item_id>
        <alt_shipment_item_id>1234567890</alt_shipment_item_id>
        <merchant_sku>B00xxxx</merchant_sku>
        <response_shipment_sku_quantity json:Integer="true">1</response_shipment_sku_quantity>
    </shipment_items>
</shipments>
```

> string jsonrequest = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

```
{"shipments":[
    {
        "shipment_tracking_number":null,
        "response_shipment_date":"2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00",
        "response_shipment_method":"UPS Ground",
        "expected_delivery_date":"2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00",
        "ship_from_zip_code":"12345",
        "carrier_pick_up_date":"2016-10-18T01:00:00.0000000-04:00",
        "carrier":"UPS",
        "shipment_items":[
        {
            "shipment_item_id":"FF12345K",
            "alt_shipment_item_id":"1234567890",
            "merchant_sku":"B00xxxx",
            "response_shipment_sku_quantity":"1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I need `"response_shipment_sku_quantity":"1"` to show up as `"response_shipment_sku_quantity":1`, but it doesnt seem to be working. I can modify the XML or the code that performs the conversion. I dont mind which as long as this can be done.

Comment: Are you using the "forked" version of `XmlNodeConverter` described in [convert a Json value to Integer with Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909328/convert-a-json-value-to-integer-with-newtonsoft)?

Answer (score 1):

You define the attribute wrongly. This is how it should look like.

```
<response_shipment_sku_quantity json:Type='Integer'>1</response_shipment_sku_quantity>
```

**EDIT:**

[**Newtonsoft.Json XmlNodeConverter**](https://github.com/lukegothic/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs)

Look methods `private void SerializeNode` and `string dataType = GetDataType(node);` they suggest this definition.

Another option is to `Deserialize` the `xml` to `class` with proper types for the properties and after that `Serialize` it to `Json`.

Comment: I tried running this by putting it in the node on the xml file and it doesnt seem to be having any affect. I unfortunately have no ability to add the array code in the file itself. I have written code to check if there is only 1 node with the same name and if so it will add the array attribute. Could this be overriding it somehow? The sample above is the xml that i got from doc.innerxml, so this is after my code has done its business

Comment: @DanHastings you can check my edit and look the source code.