# How to stop JsonConvert.SerializeObject from changing ints to strings when converting XML to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to prevent Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method to replace integers with strings? Sample code below:

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xml = @"<data><someProperty>12345</someProperty></data>";
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
```

The current output is

```
{"data":{"someProperty":"12345"}}
```

whereas the output I want is

```
{"data":{"someProperty":12345}}
```

Comment: "If the XML created from JSON doesn't match what you want, then you will need to convert it manually. The best approach to do this is to load your JSON into a LINQ to JSON object like JObject or JArray and then use LINQ to create an XDocument. The opposite process, using LINQ with an XDocument to create a JObject or JArray, also works. You can find out more about using LINQ to JSON with LINQ" https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

Comment: does xml have type information for numbers? seems not?

Comment: On second thought, if you implement a custom JsonWriter, then you can intercept the string, try to parse it, and write the value differently.

Comment: I do wonder about the use case, are they known objects? Any string value might at some time contain a number. (for example a street number), which could make continuity a problem. I don't know if it matters for this scenario, but I would prefer deserializing the xml to a strongly typed object. Of course I am not sure if you know all the objects before hand?

Comment: Not implemented out of the box, see [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18611139/3744182) or [convert a Json value to Integer with Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29909328/3744182) for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you override `JsonTextWriter` you should be able to intercept every string value, try to parse it, and write it out differently.

```cs
public class XmlIntWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public XmlIntWriter(TextWriter textWriter) : base(textWriter)
    {
    }
    public override void WriteValue(string value)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(value, out var i))
            this.WriteValue(i);
        else
            base.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

Using your custom writer with the Newtonsoft xml converter is a little fiddly, but should look something like;

```cs
public static void Serialise(XDocument doc, TextWriter writer)
{
    var converter = new XmlNodeConverter ();
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = new JsonConverter[] { converter }
    };
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
    using var xmlWriter = new XmlIntWriter(writer);
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, doc);
}
```

(I haven't tested any of this)

Comment: You might want to use the invariant culture, i.e. `int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out var i)`