# Attribute json:Type does not work when SerializeXmlNode

Tags: xml, json.net

I am trying to convert XML to JSON using SerializeXmlNode. Everything works fine except the **json:Type** attribute. Any help?

```
InputXml := '<root xmlns:json=''http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json''><root json:Array=''true''><name>abc</name><qty json:Type=''Integer''>1</qty></root></root>';

XmlDocument := XmlDocument.XmlDocument;
XmlDocument.LoadXml(InputXml);

OutputJSON := JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(XmlDocument.DocumentElement, JsonFormatting.Indented, TRUE);
```

The attribute json:Array works correctly but json:Type seems to be ignored (I need **"qty": 1** but the number is in quotes).

```
{
  "root": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "qty": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any hint how to make it work?

Comment: There is no functionality `json:Type=''Integer''` in Json.NET to specify primitive type when converting from XML.  See [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean #1651](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1651) which is currently open, and also [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18611139/3744182) and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737544/3744182) to [Force JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode to serialize node value as an Integer or a Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18611139/3744182) points to https://github.com/lukegothic/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs which includes `json:Type` functionality -- but unfortunately that code was forked from Json.NET in 2013 and is very much out of date.

Comment: Would an answer that gives a workaround be acceptable?

Comment: I’ll be back on Wednessday and let you know. However thanks for the efford.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the workaround but it is not a solution for me as I work with completely dynamic code + use specific (limited) development environment.I finally solved it my way: used unique keywords (before and after the values) and replace them in post-processing using REGEX. It's a kind of old school technique but I have no other option. Thank you.