# How to set json:Type="Decimal" Attribute in XMLNode C#

Tags: c#, attributes, decimal, xmldocument, xmlnode

I want to set the attribute json:Type="Decimal" into a XML Node.

I have the XML Document

```
<root>
 <a>12.55</a>
 <b>Test</b>
</root>
```

Now I want to set the attribute

```
json:Type="Decimal"
```

in the XML Node

```
<a>12.55</a>
```

that it looks like

```
<a json:Type="Decimal">12.55</a>
```

I tried with the following Code

```
XmlAttribute att = Doc.CreateAttribute("Type");
att.Prefix = "json";
att.Value = "Decimal";
node.Attributes.Append(att);
```

but the result is

```
<a Type="Decimal">12.55</a>
```

Who can help me!

[The original question is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611139/force-jsonconvert-serializexmlnode-to-serialize-node-value-as-an-integer-or-a-bo)

Comment: CreateAttribute has an overload that takes also a prefix. Use that one. The solution presented in the link is wild. I'm sure that never made it into Json.Net. If you want conversion between Xml and Json rather look at the other answer and create a proper class to serialize/deserialize for both formats and use that as intermediate.

Comment: That overload takes a full URI, not a prefix, as its name is `namespaceURI`. You then have to declare the prefix to use for that namespace URI somewhere, either on that element or on some ancestor element, like so: `xmlns:json="..."`. Learnabout XML namespaces. It's not as simple as just adding a prefix.